# Automatically copy dependencies in DUB for Derelict

Tags: d, derelict3

I'm creating a Derelict application and apparently derelict needs the shared libraries to be in the root path. Is there a way to do this using DUB, without copying the files over manually into the `./bin` folder? (Just have them get copied when building automatically)

Also I am assuming the .so files for Linux systems will have to be in the binary folder too. I know there is `"copyFiles"` but where will the files get copied from, where will they get copied to? Is this cross-platform?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you'd normally just have the necessary libraries installed system wide using your distribution's package manager.

On Windows DLLs are often placed in the application's folder and `copyFiles` exists for exactly this reason.

This is what I have in my DUB package.json for an application that uses Derelict GLFW and Derelict FreeImage:

```json
"copyFiles": [
    "lib/glfw3.dll",
    "lib/FreeImage.dll"
]
```

The files are copied from the `lib` folder in the root of my project and they are copied to the random temporary folder dub uses for building (I imagine on linux it's somewhere in /tmp and on Windows it's in somewhere like %APPDATA%\Temp\dub).

Comment: The problem is though, those files aren't present in my directory, they are in the derelict one.

Comment: Derelict doesn't ship with any binaries to my knowledge. What files are you referring to?

Comment: Linux does however require it's own libraries in the binary path, I suppose I have to use the OS suffix?